# Feeding back into a rail of a power source

Tags: power-supply

I have a power supply with +12v, +5v, and GND rails.

Is it good practice to put a 7v motor across the 5 and 12v rails?

Comment: No. I doubt it even gets counted as a practice (let alone be best). I would rather term it 'cruel', however it would work( if both 5v and 12v share the same ground).

Comment: @vvy what if the power supply has a -12v rail, and you put a motor from +5 to -12? I can't think of other reasons that it would have one.

Comment: That would only work if your 5V rail can *sink* current. Most supplies would not work in this way.

Comment: @brhans what about a pc power supply?

Comment: almost certainly not.

Comment: Do you need more than 5/7 of the motor's rated speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a good way to destroy everything connected between +5 and GND.

The motor will draw a lot of current (especially on start-up) and that will typically cause the +5V rail to rise up towards +12.

Most (positive) switching supplies and linear regulators are not designed to sink current from the output, only to source it, so as soon as the motor current exceeds the draw of everything else on the +5V line you'll have disaster.

Below is part of a schematic of a 200W PC power supply from [here](http://www.pavouk.org/hw/atxps.png):

[image]

As you can see if you connect a resistor between +12 and +5 SBD1/D83-004 will become reverse biased and there is nothing keeping the +5V rail from rising other than capacitor leakage (the feedback might switch the supply down in time, if you are lucky).